# 404 when submitting form data to sql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I keep submitting form input or attempting to do so I get a 404 with this PHP at the end of the url its in the top of the php snippit I am unsure if that is a clue to the issue. I have the action linked to `insert.php` I am unsure what is going on. Everything to me looks correct. But obviously its not. I've made sure the `header('location: index.html')` is correct. As another post suggested. Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign Up</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/live/app-d159020cbe.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/live/core-89ce772293.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="containsignuptext">
        <p>We believe the developer community is stronger togeather, We believe it takes the right community for us to reach the next stage in the future we believe in adding real tools to developers tool belts.</p>
    </div>
    <form action="insert.php" method="POST"  accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="loginForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login_email" class="sr-only">Full Name</label>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required="required" name="fullname" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login_email" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" name="username" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="login_email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" name="email" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="login_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" name="password" type="password">
            <div>
                <label for="login_email" class="sr-only">Codelangs</label>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" id="codelang" placeholder="Code Language You Like the Most" required="required" name="codelangs" type="text">
            </div>
            <button method="POST" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in" type="submit" name="insert">
                <span class="ladda-label">Get Hacking</span>
            </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

I get that in the url idk if it helps the rest is the inser.php code.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Placeholder";
$pass = "FakeForShow";
$dbname = "sign up new";


$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$codelangs=$_POST['codelangs'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO newusers (fullname, username, password, email, codelang)
VALUES ( '$fullname', '$username', '$email',  '$password', '$codelangs');";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("location: index.html");
} 
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>
```

Comment: 404 means your path in action is not correct / valid.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: What is `<?php%20echo%20$_SERVER[%27PHP_SELF%27];?> ` and where does that fit into your code/question?

Comment: As i said it is the url I get back I am not sure if it might be a clue as to what is the problem. I am supposed to share everything I think fits into the question. Idk how the action path is not correct, especially since its insert.php. Thank you for all the information about the passwords ect. I am new to this. I really just need it to submit the data right now. Security is on my mind but idk how to even make it work to secure anything.

Comment: That string isn't produced in any of the code you've posted. There must be more going on that you haven't told us about.

Comment: you need to switch email and password around on your values section of your query.

Comment: @Jonny that did help me get one step closer now I just need to make sure my sql connection information is correct. because it runs the code and just says connection failed now. No 404

Comment: be sure about URL of insert.php in the  relative dir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might help you.

The HTML Code : `index.php`

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sign Up</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/live/app-d159020cbe.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/live/core-89ce772293.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="containsignuptext">
            <p>We believe the developer community is stronger togeather, We believe it takes the right community for us to reach the next stage in the future we believe in adding real tools to developers tool belts.</p>

        </div>
        <form action="insert.php" method="POST"  accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="loginForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login_email" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" name="username" type="text">
            </div>
            <!-- Other form elements-->
            <button method="POST" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in" type="submit" name="insert">
                <span class="ladda-label">Get Hacking</span>
            </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP Code : `insert.php`

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$db_username = "DB_USER_NAME";
$db_pass = "DB_USER_PASSWORD";
$dbname = "DB_NAME";

$username = $_POST['username'];
// Other POST elements

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $db_username, $db_pass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO newusers (username) VALUES ('$username');";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("location: index.php");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

You can add more form elements, Javascript Validations etc as per your requirement.

Comment: This helped me because it helped me notice that I was using the same value id for the database information as the form information that allowed me to change the $username to $dbusername and actually connect!

Answer (score 0):

Your database connection should be similar to this.

```
$s = 'localhost';
$u = 'root';
$p = 'yourUsername';
$d = 'yourPassword';
$mysqli = new mysqli($s, $u, $p, $d);
```

Check to see if the butt is clicked first.

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
```

Do some Error Checks like this you need to add to this this is very basic.

```
$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$codelangs=$_POST['codelangs'];   
$alert = '';    
$errorFullname = '';
if($_POST['fullname'] == '' || $_POST['username'] || $_POST['email'] || $_POST['password']){
if($_POST['fullname'] == ''){$errorFullname "Cannot be empty.";}//and so on...
$alert = "All fields are required.";} else {
```

If no Errors insert.  Encrypt your passwords before inserting them.

```
$hashedWord = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 17));
$insertdata = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO  newusers (fullname, username, password, email, codelang) VALUES('"$fullname"', '"$username"',  '"$hashedWord"', '"$email"', '"$codelangs"') ");
$insertdata->execute();
$insertdata->close();      
header("location: index.html");
}
}
include 'YourHtmlPage';
```

You can call the error messages like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="login_email" class="sr-only">Full Name</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" required="required" name="fullname" type="text">
</div>
<div><?php echo $errorFullname; ?></div>
```

You can use something like this to check the hashed password.  Run a select and match it with what they typed.

```
password_verify($passwordTheyTyped, $YourHashedPassFromTheDatabase);
```

Hope it helps a little.